# Detect if SSD is faulty

Tags: windows-7, ssd

Every time I boot the SSD on Win7 I get a message: "One or more of your disks needs to be checked for consistency." After running scannow, it said that some of my files are corrupt and cannot be repaired. Is there a way I can test if the hard drive is faulty vs a problem with the Windows installation?

Answer (score 1):

What brand of SSD?

Intel have the [SSD toolbox](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18455) for their kit

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you can't do a "clean" from scratch install of Windows (or your favorite OS, as long as it's stable after installation), you are *definitely* looking at defective hardware somewhere in the system.

Can you swap the SSD with another drive, do another clean OS install, and see if you have the same problem? That would isolate the drive as the faulty component.

I've seen bad memory also cause issues like this, for example...

Answer (score 0):

Coptact Kingston Support, see what they say.

http://www.kingston.com/support/ssdnow/default.asp

.